# CSS in mail template doesn't work

Tags: html, css, email, templates

I tried to send mail from some simple mail service and it worked perfectly, but in other system, CSS doesn't load and is displayed in mail body.
There's something like that:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        body,
......
</style>
```

and I see on the beginning

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        body,
```

The document is quite long, so I don't want to change every single cell attribute to those from CSS. Is there any way to do it without restructuring all code?

@edit: The other system is SysAid, it's a helpdesk system. I'm trying to change default email notification to something better.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'in other system'? Media queries are not widely supported in email clients and web mail services.

Comment: I think you need to unsubscribe from media queries as they are not supported by the postal services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [media query support chart](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/).

Are you inlining your CSS? You'll need to do this particularly for Gmail as it doesn't support the `<style>` tag at all.

Here is a [list of CSS inlining tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code/17882057#17882057) so you don't have to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are not well supported in email applications and services. You can reference [this excellent chart from Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) which will help you code compatible email templates.